# Form value not populated by javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have a link which calls some javascript. The javascript populates a form value and submits it. Works fine in all browsers except internet explorer.

All other options on the page are links, thats why I also would like this option to be a link

thanks

```
        <script type="text/javascript">



        function timeZone(){

            today = new Date()
            difference = today.getTimezoneOffset()

            var field = document.getElementById("form").timezone
            alert("test")
            if(difference < 0){
                difference = difference * -1
                field.value =  "GMT+"  + pad(Math.floor(difference/60), 2) + ":" + pad(difference%60, 2);
            }
            else{
                field.value = "GMT-"  + pad(Math.floor(difference/60), 2) + ":" + pad(difference%60, 2);
            }
            form = document.getElementById('form');
            form.submit();


        }

        function pad(num, digits) {
            num = String(num); while (num.length < digits) { num="0"+num; }; return num;
        }

    </script>









                    <form method="get" action="ViewLog.do?page=1" id="form">
                        <input id="timezone" name="timezone" type="hidden" value=""></input>
                        <img id="activityHistoryImage" Class = "navImage" src="imgs/history.png" alt="Activity history"/>


                        <a   href="ViewLog.do?page=1"id ="activityHistoryButton"class = "navButton" onclick="timeZone(); return false">Activity history</a><br/>
                        <small class="navSubText">See your most recent activities </small>
                    </form>
```

Comment: Always declare your variables with `var`.

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer may or may not have issues with the fact that you've given an id of 'form' to your `form` element; I imagine it probably does. In general, it's best to avoid using tag names as the value on `id` or `name` attributes.

Also, your hidden input element has an id, yet you're not using it to reference it. Change:

```
var field = document.getElementById("form").timezone
```

to

```
var field = document.getElementById("timezone");
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Declare variables with **var**.
2. Place `;` where they should be.

Comment: It's not mistake actually :). Javascript allows skipping `;` but is not good style anyway.